# Mockery NoMatchingExpectationException thrown when using with(Mockery::on(Closure))

Tags: php, mockery

I am having an interesting issue. When executing...

```
$lenderMailer->shouldReceive('sendDonationMail')->once();
```

my tests pass without a problem. But then, if I try:

```
$lenderMailer->shouldReceive('sendDonationMail')->once()->with(\Mockery::on(function(){
    return true;
}));
```

I am getting a NoMatchingExpectationException. The signature of the sendDonationMail method is

```
public function sendDonationMail(Lender $lender, Money $donationAmount)
```

Any ideas why the exception is thrown?

Comment: What is the signature of the real `sendDonationMail` method?

Comment: Added the signature to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup expectations for all arguments, currently you are only verifying the `$lender` argument with your closure.

This should work for example:

```
$lenderMailer->shouldReceive('sendDonationMail')->once()->with(\Mockery::on(function(){ return true; }), \Mockery::any());
```